# An extremely strange phenomenon

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-8, network-printer, multi-function-printer

Today i experienced a rather strange phenomenon. There may of been a simple reason behind it but i can't seem to graph it, i am hoping someone else can pinpoint the cause of this.

Initially i planned to use a desktop PC and a printer, connecting them with a USB cable.
I have been using this setup for years, with no problems.
Then, i simply unplugged it. Went over to another place and tried to use it again.

It worked fine, but after a system restart it practically became a ghost. It was not being detected, i tried to install it on two other computers , one of which is a isolated laptop but it still didn't work.

Later when i came home and re-setup the printer in the same configuration, it worked. It also installed perfectly on the other PCs.
As well as that, the desktops ran windows xp and 8, while the laptop ran windows 7

Any ideas as to why this could of happened?

Comment: The simplest explaination would be a bad USB port.  Without more information about what troubleshooting steps you did while it wasn't working it might not be possible to determine what went wrong.  Unless this happens again I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: It happened once earlier, and i'd much rather that it didn't happen again. I also tried to purchase brand new connector cables, no help..

Comment: Have you ruled out the device itself is to blame?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning it Off and On again?

Been waiting for a while to use this. Well joking aside from your story the only difference from printer not working at the office to it working at home is the printer was turned off and on again. It is possible when you rebooted your machine something happened to the printer that it did want to communicate to another PC, once it was turned off and later turned back on it reconnected. Plug and Play is not always as PnP like advertised.